# How can i make a switch button and check if button was clicked more then once?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A click event:

```
private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Test();
        }
```

Once i clicked it's calling Test:

```
    List<string> listv;
    private void Test()
    {
           for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(20,1000); i++)
            {
                string rand = RandomString(200);
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(rand);
            }
            textBox4.Enabled = true;

            listv = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                             .Select(item => item.Text)
                             .ToList();

            ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
            textBox4.Enabled = false;            
    }
```

What i want to do is when i click the button first time do only the part in Test:

```
for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(20,1000); i++)
                {
                    string rand = RandomString(200);
                    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(rand);
                }
                textBox4.Enabled = true;

                listv = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(item => item.Text)
                                 .ToList();
```

And if i click second time on the button make the second part:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
textBox4.Enabled = false;
```

Then again each time clicked switch and make the other part in Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Keep a counter of how many times the button has been clicked. Since you only have two options, its sufficient to check to see if _clickCounter is odd or even to switch between the two functionalities.

Edit: If you don't care about keeping track of how many times the button has been clicked and will only ever have two options, you could just change _clickCounter to a boolean.

```
private int _clickCounter = 0;
private void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_clickCounter % 2 == 0)
    {
        Test();
    }
    else
    {
        Clear();
    }
    _clickCounter++;
}

private void Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < random.Next(20,1000); i++)
    {
        string rand = RandomString(200);
        ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(rand);
    }
    textBox4.Enabled = true;

    listv = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                         .Select(item => item.Text)
                         .ToList();      
}

private void Clear() //whatever you want to name it
{
    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Clear();
    textBox4.Enabled = false;      
}
```